# Parsing a DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datagridview

I'm trying to write an application in C# that will analyze two different data sets and try to find matches between them.  My question is, what would be the best way for me to go through the data rows and extract data from them?

I would need to extract entire rows of data, with multiple columns, and analyze them for similarities.

Would the best way be to put the row into a string and parse it?

EDIT: This is the code I'm using to put the data in a DataGridView it's from an excel spreadsheet:

```
try
                {
                    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
                    connStringBuilder.DataSource = file;
                    connStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
                    connStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX1");

                    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

                    DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();

                    DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
                    selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [All Carpets to Excel$]";

                    DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                    connection.ConnectionString = connStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

                    selectCommand.Connection = connection;

                    adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;

                    data = new DataSet();

                    adapter.Fill(data);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tables[0].DefaultView;



                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }
```

I haven't tried any code to analyze and compare just yet, but I first need to know what the best way to access the data and format it.

Thanks!

Comment: Should it be DataGridView? Can you compare the data sources that were bound to the DataGridViews?

Comment: The data is put in a datagridview for GUI purposes.  Should I compare the sources instead?

Comment: Unless the data is changed in UI, I would say the Datasource comparision is much better since you need not reconstruct the datasource again..

Comment: Too little detail here to give a good answer. There are a lot of different ways to approach this kind of thing. It would help to know how you are accessing the data sets (EF, plain ADO.NET, strongly-typed, etc.) and how you're defining what constitutes acceptable similarity. Also, have you got any code that you've tried that you can post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to work with List objects, and use LINQ to run compares and run queries. Here is an example of taking a DataSet (your 'data' property from your example) and getting a DataTable from it. Then I loop through the rows & columns and populate a List. The last line is just an example of using a LINQ query on the new List.

```
DataSet grid = new DataSet();
            DataTable table = grid.Tables[0];

            List<string> tableData = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    tableData.Add(row[i].ToString());
                }
            }

            tableData.Where(x => x == "TestValue");
```

Let me know if there are questions on this.

Comment: The "DataSet Grid = new DataSet();" would be the same as "data" in my code?  If so, I think I understand it.

Comment: This is a LINQ to object query. There are LOTS of things you can do with LINQ, and it is really powerful for querying and comparing data. [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a good link to get your feet wet with LINQ.